# In C#, using .editorconfig, is there any way to force developers to declare every parameter is either nullable or not allowed?

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception, arguments, nullable, editorconfig

In C#, I can express a parameter is nullable in a method's signature like:

```
private void doSomething(string? value)
```

Similarly, I can express a parameter must not be null like:

```
private void doSomething(string value!!)
```

Does any rule exist -- or is there any way I can create a rule -- for .editorconfig which will force developers on a project to always declare in a method's signature whether each input parameter allows null?

If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt such a rule will be made. Null parameter checking with !! is better suited for public APIs as a safeguard. If there are long internal call stacks, applying null checks puts a strain on performance that may not be necessary.

Sticking to nullable reference types everywhere else is more appropriate because it has no impact on performance at runtime. With nullable reference types enabled, a value declared with neither ? or !! is implied to not support null and will lead to the relevant warnings.